# FileNotFoundException: The file "MySql.Data.resources" could not be found

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When running EF 6 with MySql I can use the EF perfectly, but as soon as I start writing to the database using

```
        var newSession = new SessionModel();
        _context.Sessions.Add(newSession);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

I get this, as soon as it gets to `SaveChanges`:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An error occurred while
>   starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file
>   "MySql.Data.resources" could not be found

I have installed the files to the GAC including

- Mysql.Data.dll
- Mysql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, the resolver was looking for de-DE satellites for Mysql.Data.Resources and couldnt find it.

Setting

```
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");            
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

in the Startup.cs helped out.